# In C#, if all interface members are public and abstract by default, why can't we use override in implementing class?

Tags: c#, syntax, interface, abstract-class, abstract

In C#, if all interface members are public and abstract by default, why can't we use override in implementing class? While we can use override in abstract classes.

```
interface IExample
{
    int Ara();
}
class Matematiksel : IExample
{
    
    public override int Ara()
    {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

CS0115 : Matematiksel.Ara() : no suitable method found to override.
abstract class Example

```
{
    public abstract int Ara();
}
class Math1 : Example
{
    public override int Ara()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

1st one does not work while the second one works just fine.

Comment: Well I have read that one before posting. It does not explain why it is not possible to it and it does not refer to abstract class or methods or interfaces having abstract members by default.

Comment: Think of an interface as a specification or a schema.  It is a technical description of what must be implemented in your class.  So then a class which uses an interface must as a minimum implement the code to actually meet the specification.

Comment: Interface methods are abstract in the sense that they _must_ be implemented. Not the same "abstract" as in the keyword. In abstract classes or classes designed to be inherited from you need the keyword to distinguish between virtual and abstract members. And then you need override keyword to distinguish between exactly that and hiding (`new`). There is none of that when implementing an interface.

Comment: If your concern is to mark it explicitly as a member from that interface, you can do so "softly" by documenting it via XML Docs or you can explicitly implement it. But note that the latter will have an effect on the visibility of the method.

Comment: Like Java, C# has a distinction between *inheriting* a base class and *implementing* an interface. Whereas Java encodes these concepts in different keywords (`inherits` and `implements`), C# does not. The class doesn't inherit the members from the interface because it's not a base class, so there's nothing to override yet. You're introducing a new method. In fact, it's still a class method. It's actually not bound to the interface until run time.

Comment: ["Why" something is the way it is ,is not a good question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585) You should clearly describe what kind of answer you are looking for. To me, it seems like you just don't like C#'s syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Interface methods and abstract methods are two different concepts.

By defining a member in the interface `IExample`, you require that whatever class or struct implements `IExample` (or an interface that inherits from `IExample`) must have a member with a matching signature. For methods, the matching method can be abstract or virtual, but it must be public or an explicit implementation. At compile time, it is determined for each implementing class and struct which members are the ones that satisfy the requirement and are defined as the implementations. Interfaces have a few more options than abstract methods if they use generics in combination with `in` and `out` co- and contra-variant modifiers. For properties, an interface may require a `get` when the implementing property has `get` and `set`.

If you define an `abstract` member, that is a different type of requirement for inheriting classes. Most notably abstract members can be protected, and abstraction only exists for classes, since structs cannot be inherited to implement abstract members. The signature of an abstract method has well-defined types, co- and contra-variants do not exist in this context.

You can also define a `virtual` method. This tells the runtime that there may be a more specific method to call when calling the method from any level within the type hierarchy. Therefore calling a virtual method means the runtime has to look uo the "best" method in the virtual method lookup table of the type definition, and then call that one, independent of the variable type. However virtual methods are still actual methods that have a method body and can be called with `base.`.

`abstract` and `virtual` are much more closely related concepts, with the difference being that `abstract` says "there is no actual method body to call down here".

For an interface variable, it was explicitly defined which method would be called and that mapping takes precedence. For abstract and virtual, the runtime has to look up the actual method to call.

The `override` keyword is only used for `abstract` and `virtual` cases, and not for `interface`. It refers to overriding actual method definitions down in the inheritance hierarchy, whereas an interface is merely a mold that a given class or struct has to fit into, and where the interface members are wired to the actual member that is regarded as the implementation at compile time.

Could C# have been designed that you also must write `override` when you implement an interface method? Yes. But it's simply not how they defined the language.